# Angular2 loads all resources needed on Login Page

Tags: angular, authentication, single-page-application

I have an angular 2 application that has a lots of routes and components. As the application itself is an SPA and I don't have any problem with it but whenever I login all these components needs to load first before i can go to private pages of the app.

What are the strategy to make the app to load only what is needed by login component only without loading the entire application?

Answer (score 1):

You want to make use of angular2 router's lazy module loading features. The official documentation is a good starting point, here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#asynchronous-routing